# Best way to convert arabic to hex in custom code table in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, hex, arabic

I'm currently working on a new program to print receipts which contain arabic text. The printer can handle these characters, but uses a special code table to print them. Therefore all information sent to the printer must be in hex. Information sent to the printer can have a mix of both arabic and non arabic characters.

The code table is here(page 133 http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/dwY-TM-T88V_TechRefGuide.pdf)

For example, ق = E7, ك = E8

With a standard hex conversion (below) the first 128 latin alphanumeric characters work just fine, but arabic are displayed as question marks.

```
byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
var hexstring = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to convert to the correct hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this myself in case anyone else has a similar issue.

So the scenario was trying to send Arabic characters to a TM-T88iV Epson printer. Firstly, You need the TM-T88V or later to support Arabic.

Secondly, characters must be sent to the printer as Bytes using a Write command rather than as a String in a WriteLine. The Write command needs to terminate with a CRLF in order for the printer to print. The printer has no Right-to-Left funtion, so the Bytes sent to the printer need to be inverted first: Array.Reverse(byte[])

In order to get visual studio to convert arabic characters to the correct hex values, you need to change the windows code table. This is usually done in Control panel > region & language > administrative > language for non-unicode.
Windows default for UK was 850. Arabic (U.A.E) is 720. You can double check by running cmd and typing chcp. As it turns out, **Arabic U.A.E 720 is NOT correct**, you need 1256. I couldn't find the matching language in control panel, so I changed it manually in cmd using the command 'chcp 1256'

Finally, you need to change the internal code table of the printer. To do this, I used the TM-T88V utility (https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4100&pcat=3&scat=42). I believe you can do this via direct commands sent via serial too, but it proved too fiddly.

Fingers crossed this should all work now. Happy printing.